# order on positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know that the set of positive matrix (ie. The matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $^tA = A$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\geq 0$) is a convex cone.

Thank do this we can defined a order relation on the set of positive matrix. So we can say that $M \geq N$ iff $M-N$ is is still in the cone, which means $M-N$ has positive eigenvalues.

But what are the property of this order relation ? 
For example can I multiply both sides of the inequality by an arbitrary matrix ? Like if $M \geq N$ then for any matrix $A \in M_n$, we have $AM \geq AN$ and $MA \geq NA$ ?

I think it's possible to multiply both sides by a scalar (and if it's negative we reverse the inequality).
More generally what can I do with this inequality, and what are it's properties ?

Thank you !